# ConcurrentHasnMap has duplicate key when size are big

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, hbase

I have 975,641 rows of pure string data as rowkeys for HBase, where the lengths of the strings vary. After using distinct in MySQL to remove duplicates, there are 884,508 unique data entries.

When I use multiple threads to read data from the database in batches and write them to HBase, I encounter the following issue:
I start 50 threads in a loop, and each thread reads 1,000 rows of data in batches. I use a ConcurrentHashMap to deduplicate the rowkeys within each thread.

After completing all the loops, an AtomicInteger shows that 975,641 rows of data were processed correctly.
At this point, the size of the ConcurrentHashMap is 884,979, which is 471 more entries than expected.

When I store the keySet of the ConcurrentHashMap in MySQL and deduplicate the rowkeys, I find that there are 471 duplicate entries. The correct number of unique rowkeys is indeed 884,508.

After multiple tests, I have observed that the specific duplicate entries stored in MySQL vary each time. However, the occurrence of 471 duplicate entries can be consistently reproduced. Furthermore, the keySet of the ConcurrentHashMap always has 471 extra entries, even when the original data remains unchanged.

This issue does not occur when the original number of rowkeys is relatively small.

Below is my code:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class HbaseSupportServiceImplV2 extends HbaseSupportServiceImpl implements HbaseMigrationService {
    @Resource
    protected MPRawDataService rawDataSourceMybatisPlus;

    protected ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    protected CountDownLatch processCountDownLatch;

    protected volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> rowKeyMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    protected final static DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    private static final Integer pageSize = 1000;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeExecutor() {
        int cpuCoreNum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                50,
                100,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000),
                new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("hbase-migration-%d").build(),
                new RejectFreeDiscardPolicy());
    }


    @Override
    public List<JSONObject> migrateMysql2Hbase(Mysql2HbaseMigrationForm reqForm) throws Exception {
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(reqForm.getStartDate(), DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(reqForm.getEndDate(), DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        String tableName = reqForm.getTableName();


        //return log
        List<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<>();

        //process one day each time
        LocalDate thatDate = startDate;

        while (!thatDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //total row from raw data
            long totalCount = rawDataSourceMybatisPlus.count(new LambdaQueryWrapper<RawData>()
                    .eq(RawData::getDate, thatDate));

            //calculate total page
            long totalPage = totalCount / pageSize + (totalCount % pageSize == 0 ? 0 : 1);

            //start a new count down latch to ensure 50 threads(pages) running at the same time
            if (totalPage > 50) {
                processCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(50);
            } else {
                processCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch((int) (totalPage));
            }

            List<Future<Set<String>>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

            //loop to get paged data then send to HBase
            for (Long currentPage = 1L; currentPage <= totalPage; currentPage++) {
                Long limitOffset = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
                Long limitCount = pageSize.longValue();

                //submit task to thread pool
                Future<Set<String>> submit = executor.submit(new BatchProcess(limitOffset, limitCount, thatDate, tableName, currentPage));
                taskList.add(submit);

                if (currentPage % 50 == 0) {
                    //when reach to 50 pages, wait for all 50 pages to finish
                    try {
                        processCountDownLatch.await();
                        //print log when each 50 pages finished
                        log.info("thatDate={},currentPage={},taotalPage={},remainPage={}",
                                thatDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
                                currentPage,
                                totalPage,
                                totalPage - currentPage);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        NotifiableLog.ERROR.print("countDown wait error", e);
                    }

                    //reset count down latch 
                    if (totalPage - currentPage > 50) {
                        //for next 50 pages
                        processCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(50);
                    } else {
                        //for remain pages less equal than 50
                        processCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch((int) (totalPage - currentPage));
                    }
                } else if (currentPage == totalPage) {
                    // when reach to last page, wait for all pages to finish
                    try {
                        processCountDownLatch.await();
                        //print log when each 50 pages finished
                        log.info("thatDate={},currentPage={},taotalPage={},remainPage={}",
                                thatDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
                                currentPage,
                                totalPage,
                                totalPage - currentPage);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        NotifiableLog.ERROR.print("countDown waiting error", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            //analyze result
            Long totalSuccessCount = 0L;
            for (Future<Set<String>> future : taskList) {
                try {
                    totalSuccessCount += future.get().size();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //just email me and continue
                    NotifiableLog.ERROR.print("async has error", e);
                }
            }

            try {
                log.info("succeed，now date={},total MySQL rows={},rowkey count={}",
                        thatDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
                        totalCount,
                        rowKeyMap.size()
                );
                JSONObjectBuilder currentProcessLog = new JSONObjectBuilder()
                        .put("date", thatDate.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER))
                        .put("totalCount", totalCount)
                        .put("totalSuccessCount", totalSuccessCount)
                        .put("processTimeUsageMillis", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                result.add(currentProcessLog.build());

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                throw e;
            }

            thatDate = thatDate.plusDays(1);
        }

        return result;
    }

    class BatchProcess implements Callable<Set<String>> {
        private final long limitOffset;
        private final long limitCount;
        private final LocalDate thatDate;
        private final String tableName;
        private final Long order;

        public BatchProcess(long limitOffset, long limitCount, LocalDate thatDate, String tableName, Long order) {
            this.limitOffset = limitOffset;
            this.limitCount = limitCount;
            this.thatDate = thatDate;
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.order = order;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> call() throws Exception {
            try {
                return actualProcess();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                NotifiableLog.ERROR.print("async task error", e);
                throw e;
            } finally {
                processCountDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }

        private Set<String> actualProcess() throws Exception {
            // query data from MySQL
            // this will perform a select below:
            // SELECT rowkey FROM tableName WHERE date = #{thatDate} LIMIT #{limitOffset}, #{limitCount}
            List<RawData> page = rawDataSourceMybatisPlus.multithreadDirectList(
                    limitOffset,
                    limitCount,
                    thatDate);

            if (page.isEmpty()) {
                //skip when query result is empty
                NotifiableLog.ERROR.print("query result is empty offset={},date={}", limitOffset, thatDate);
                return new HashSet<>();
            }

            //construct rowkey and HBase data from query result
            List<SaveHbaseDetailForm> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
            Set<String> rowkeyInThisBatch = new HashSet<>();
            page.stream()
                    .forEach(e -> {
                        //construct rowkey from query result
                        String rowkey = String.format("%s-%s-%s-%s-%s",
                                e.getMarketId() == null ? "null" : e.getMarketId(),
                                e.getSku() == null ? "null" : e.getSku(),
                                e.getUseAdv() == null ? "null" : e.getUseAdv(),
                                e.getFetchDate() == null ? "null" : e.getFetchDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")),
                                e.getName() == null ? "null" : e.getName());
                        List<SaveHbaseDetailForm> rowDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(JSONObject.toJSONString(e));
                        jsonObject.forEach((k, v) -> {
                            SaveHbaseDetailForm data = new SaveHbaseDetailForm();
                            data.setColumn(k);
                            data.setCf("rank");
                            data.setValue(v.toString());
                            data.setRowkey(rowkey);
                            rowDataList.add(data);
                        });

                        rowkeyInThisBatch.add(rowkey);
                        rowKeyMap.putIfAbsent(rowkey, rowkey);

                        dataList.addAll(rowDataList);
                    });

            //save to hbase
            saveData(tableName, dataList, null);
            return rowkeyInThisBatch;
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't give the saving code of ConcurrentHashMap's keySet, it just shows a size of 884,979 at end of the process.

What could be causing this situation?

Comment: Be aware that the Javadoc of ConcurrentHashMap specifies that the size may be inaccurate: "Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including size, isEmpty, and containsValue are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads. Otherwise the results of these methods reflect transient states that may be adequate for monitoring or estimation purposes, but not for program control."

Comment: Just the words "unique", "concurrent" and "duplicates" by themselves seem to tell a whole story, not exactly a nice one. Many queries might be returning unique values concurrently and the resulting data might not be unique. But I see a much bigger problem here: 884979 records for a HashMap?! When you are using a DB, the resource precisely meant to deal with big sizes?! Why do you do that? Could you please explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @varocarbas I need to write the latest version of the unique ID from the daily data into the DB. There are approximately one million records of data each day, and many of them have different version numbers but duplicate IDs. I use multiple threads to handle batch processing in the form of separate pagination. Therefore, I use ConcurrentHashMap. Even if I don't use the size property of ConcurrentHashMap to print logs, the elements in ConcurrentHashMap can still have the same ID due to the excessive amount of data.

Comment: @LouisWasserman In fact, when the data volume is large (1 million records with duplicate keys), ConcurrentHashMap does exhibit the issue of having duplicate keys and loses its deduplication functionality. However, in cases of smaller data volumes (several thousand to tens of thousands of records), I have not encountered this problem.

Comment: @william But why using HashMaps (concurrent or not) at all? When dealing with so much information, the best format is precisely a DB. Why don't you create a temporary table or something like that and store all the information being managed by those HashMaps there? When dealing with so many records, I seriously doubt that relying on memory can make things faster than a DB, mainly with as heavy elements as HashMaps. And, of course, the memory usage would drop drastically. To not mention that with a DB you don't have to worry about all the concurrency issues.